# Trouble with Java Programming Editors on Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, editor, operating-system

I've checked out Eclipse and jEDit and I'm having trouble with both.

With Eclipse I can't seem to open a java file and edit it then compile it. I always have to make a new project and then copt and paste my code. It's frustrating and a time waster.

With jEdit when I open files I'v worked on on other computers I get random characters. I also can't figure out how to compile.

None of this happens when I use JCreator on my PC. Will you guys lend me a hand?

Comment: I'm guessing textedit or emacs and a command line is out of the question then? You could try Geany but you have to build that from source

Comment: It could be a file encoding issue.  When you open an existing .java file in Eclipse, does it just come up as garbage characters?

Comment: You are looking for a Programmer's File Editor, not an IDE.  IDE's tend to assume you are working on "project"s and that's what they are designed to assist.

Comment: Eclipse is a power tool for advanced users.  While learning you might like a simpler tool more suited for learners...

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is project-based. It won't just compile a file on the fly, the whole IDE is based around having projects and then adding files to the projects and then compiling and running the projects. I agree that if you only have one file you're playing around with, this is a bit inconvenient, but that's the way it is. FYI: Your Eclipse should also have an "autobuild" feature which will compile your project as changes are made so you don't need to compile before a run (which is also usually automatic). For small projects on a powerful machine, the performance hit is usually negligible.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you don't need to "COMPILE". Every time you save your Java program, you also compile it.

Just RUN the program you are writing from the **Run** menu.

Never worked with jEdit, so I can't help with that but it looks like you are having encoding problems.

I have been working on Mac OS X with Eclipse and it was a very good experience. You **definitely** don't need to create a new project every time you want to change & compile something.

Hope it helps.